# Laravel 5.4 change login input name

Tags: php, laravel

I try to have login and register forms on the same page but I don't achieve this.

I tried to rename email to login_email and password to login_password.

On my LoginController.php I add :

```
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request, [
    $this->username() => 'required', 'login_password' => 'required',
]);
}

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
return [
    $this->username() => $request->input('login_email'),
    'password'        => $request->input('login_password'),
];
}

public function username()
{
return 'login_email';
}
```

But I have this error :

> Column not found: 1054 Champ 'login_email' inconnu dans where clause (SQL: select * from `users` where `login_email` = test@gmail.com limit 1)

If I rename the column, login works but register doesn't because it search for email column.

So can I modify login input name without changing my db column name ?

Thank a lot

Edit :

Ok I go one step further and I want my login, register and password reset email forms on the same page.

Login and register are ok but how can I change my password reset email input name ??

Comment: I'm confused, you would have separate submits for both forms I assume, so why do you need a different name for those inputs? Just give both email inputs the same name. The name attribute isn't like ID you can have more than one on a page the same.

Comment: If I use the same name, I've got error on empty input even if not on the same form.

Comment: Then your form is built wrong. Those should both be separate forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found the problem :

```
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request, [
    'login_email' => 'required', 'login_password' => 'required',
]);
}

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
return [
    'email' => $request->input('login_email'),
    'password'        => $request->input('login_password'),
];
}
```